# default permalink wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I changed permalink option for my wordpress pages to custom, like this /%postname%/. Now i want default structure back i.e. ?id= but i can not find where i edit permalinks back to default structure??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be logged in with administrator privileges - but I guess you knew that already.

So go to the usual Wordpress menu, and under the 'Settings' heading, click 'Permalinks'.

Towards the top of the page is 'Common Settings' and under that, at the very top, click the option 'Default'.

Just remember, any incoming links to your site and internal links that you have added in pages or posts will be broken when you change your permalinks.